# install4j: how to create cross platform jre bundle on version8?

Tags: java, install4j

I am testing version 8 and trying to figure out jre bundles.  I think I have successfully created a jre bundle for java8 on Windows.  However, how do I do that for the Mac version since  I don't have a Mac jre on my Windows build machine that can be referenced.

Do I have to go to a Mac to generate the jre bundle?  If so, that would seem to be counter to the notion of cross platform builds.

What happened to the basic jre bundles that were downloadable in version 7?  Having every install4j user regenerate them does not seem like a step forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JRE bundle generation is cross platform. You can generate macOS JRE bundle on Windows.

> What happened to the basic jre bundles that were downloadable in version 7?

They have been discontinued. The new bundle generation is necessary for Java 9+ features and it offers a much wider variety of JDK providers.

> Having every install4j user regenerate them does not seem like a step forward.

They are generated automatically based on your project definition, there is actually less manual work involved than in install4j 7. You just specify the JDK provider and the release on the "General settings->JRE bundles" step and each new build machine will generate and cache the bundles.

Comment: Thanks, I finally did get my head around the new process.  It took a while to understand that I can generate a jre without referencing my local Java install, and then can reuse it for future builds.