# createbundle command line refuses to generate Mac bundle on Windows

Tags: install4j

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57802270/6944068 says "You can generate macOS JRE bundle on Windows."

However, my attempt failed, see transcript:

```
C:\develop\projects\id-gui\target\downloads\jre-bundles>..\install4j8.0.8\bin\createbundle C:\develop\projects\id-gui\target\downloads\jre-bundles\zulu11.41.24-sa-jdk11.0.8-macosx_x64
The JRE bundle wizard can only create JRE bundles for the platform you're currently running on.
The java home directory C:\develop\projects\id-gui\target\downloads\jre-bundles\zulu11.41.24-sa-jdk11.0.8-macosx_x64 contains a JRE for a different platform.
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cross-platform generation only applies to bundles that are generated via the mechanism configured on the "General Settings->JRE bundles" step. The `createbundle` command line tool creates "pre-created JRE bundles", in the install4j IDE you would do the same with "Project->Create a JRE bundle". Those bundles can only be generated on the platform that they are intended for because they rely on a working local installation.

Comment: "General Settings" seems to be restricted to AdoptOpenJDK, JetBrains Runtime, and Liberica - what would need to happen to support Azul Zulu? (The commercial runtime, we'd need to place it in a local directory.)

Comment: This will be added in install4j 9 next year. Currently you have to pre-create all bundles on the appropriate machines.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Please make sure to explain such restrictions when saying things like "You can generate macOS JRE bundle on Windows" in the future: Our migration from install4j 7 to 8 was made just because of the simpler JRE bundle generation, and now it turns out the effort was for naught.

Comment: If you want to deploy on macOS you need the newest instal4lj for many reasons. With the existing JDK providers JRE bundle generation does work in a cross-platform way, I don't think there was anything unclear about that in the release notes. The answer in the stackoverflow question that you linked to was in response to a specific question.